# Cocoa Bindings & Core Plot

Tags: cocoa, core-plot, cocoa-bindings

I have a pie chart working using the datasource and delegate methods for core plot, however I'm now trying to use bindings and running into some issues.

I using the following code to bind to the arraycontroller:

```
[graph addPlot:pieChart];

    // add bindings
    NSLog(@"The arranged objects are: %@", [[[self sectorAllocation] arrangedObjects] valueForKey:@"sectorPercentage"]);
    [pieChart bind:CPTPieChartBindingPieSliceWidthValues toObject:[self
                                                    sectorAllocation] withKeyPath:@"arrangedObjects.sectorPercentage"
           options:nil];

    //Set the sorting
    [[self sectorAllocation] setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:
                                         [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"sectorPercentage" ascending:YES]]];
```

It seems to be getting hung up on updateNormalizedData function.  Based on my NSlog statement my arraycontroller is returning proper values, so I have no idea what I'm doing wrong...any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You found a bug in the pie chart. I just fixed it and pushed a change to the repository. Use Mercurial to pull the latest code. If you don't want to update the whole Core Plot library, use the change [here](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/source/detail?r=6ead7ec607e17b771fb965f98fb0b425e29562fe) to patch your copy.

Comment: I was using the binary files previously, so had to change to the Dependent method...took a little time to set up, but everything is  now working, thanks.